# distinct and grab data while receiving it in php

Tags: php, jquery

i have a jquery script wich send a get var with id to a page named ajaxprocess,php each time a specific element is clicked . i have 20 elements.

the idea is create a temp table with 3 field , each time element is clicked it stores its value in field 1 , second in field 2 and third in field 3 and stop , i just want to get 3 ids stored .

here is the code. the jQuery('#test').text(data); is to test if vars were sent. the elements are all like this :  .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".element").click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('id');
        $.get('ajaxprocess.php', {
            Path: path
        }, function(data) {
            $('#test').text(data);
        });
    });
});
```

i tried to make a count but no success.
well i get perfect the first value sent when i click on an element . i want to grab this value on the database. then when i click on the second element i want to grab this second value to a second field until the third one.
how can i make this ?
please help

Comment: Some notes: Storing in the database usually happens serverside in your php script.  
$.get() is asynchronous. Quick consecutive clicks can lead to seemingly chaotic behaviour on the client side if the server answers the requests in a different order.  
Storing in the three fields is a simple algorithm. Roughly: If the first field is full, store in the second. If the second is full, store in the third.

Comment: thanks for the response , how can  i prevent this from happening so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup an ajax queue using this plugin for example : http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/
That ensures the request will get responses in the correct order.

Alternatively you can add a counter in your script, that's sent accross each request :

```
$.get('ajaxprocess.php', {
        Path: path,
        Fieldnum: fieldnum
    }, function(data) {
        $('#test').text(data);
    });
```

fieldnum++;